Different character using vim, cat and pbcopy
I have a file sample containing the following string when reading it with vim (in german language, converted from html using munpack):
benÃ¼tzt daÿs

if I cat that file, I get the following (correct) output:
$ cat sample 
benützt das

More strangely if I copy the file in the clipboard with the macos command pbcopy (thank you @Keith Thomson for the comment for the clarification on that point)
$ cat sample|pbcopy 

I get:
ben√ºtzt daˇs

Where are those differences coming from? How is it possible to have the same (correct) output from all those commands namely:
benützt das

EDIT
I added set encoding=utf-8 to by .vimrc file and manually by writing :set encoding=utf-8 in command mode but nothing changed.
I also run the following script.py:
s_list = ['Ã¼', 'ü', '√º']
for s in s_list:

  s_encoded = s.encode()
  print(f"s: {s}")
  print(f"s_encoded: {s_encoded}")
  print("len s_encoded: %d" % len(s_encoded))
  for i in range(0, len(s_encoded)):
    print(s_encoded[i])
    print(bin(s_encoded[i]))
  print("---")



and got the following output:
$ python script.py

s: Ã¼
s_encoded: b'\xc3\x83\xc2\xbc'
len s_encoded: 4
195
0b11000011
131
0b10000011
194
0b11000010
188
0b10111100
---
s: ü
s_encoded: b'\xc3\xbc'
len s_encoded: 2
195
0b11000011
188
0b10111100
---
s: √º
s_encoded: b'\xe2\x88\x9a\xc2\xba'
len s_encoded: 5
226
0b11100010
136
0b10001000
154
0b10011010
194
0b11000010
186
0b10111010
---


From my (now) basic utf-8 understanidng, when comparing the output of Ã¼ and ü, I notice the same "byte header" (195 in decimal / 0b11000011 in bin) and the same "final byte" (188 in decimal / 0b10111100 in bin).
EDIT2
I saw an answer there: https://github.com/folke/which-key.nvim/issues/254 and tried:
:set fileencoding=utf-8
but it didn't work
I also tried to open the file with the option vim -u NONE sample
but it didn't work
I also tried to open in the file with nano, there are other mojibake issue, but the one pointed in this question disappeared.
The conclusion here is that I strongly suspect that it is coming from a vim setting but I cannot find it
EDIT3
Reading comments, I performed the following diagnostic tasks:
$ file sample
sample: ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators

I also modified the vimrc and wrote and "s" to fileencodings as follows:
set fileencodings=utf-8

and indeed there was an improvement!: when reading the sample with vim, the ü was correctly displayed, however there was still an issue with the a which was displayed a? as follows:
benützt da?s

I then tried the following commands in command mode in vim (when opening the file sample with vim (right? I am supposed to execute them inside vim, correct?)
:e ++enc=utf-8 sample and :help mbyte-encoding
but nothing happened
EDIT4
I have now samplecopy which contains:
benützt da?s

its encoding is
$ samplecopy
samplecopy: UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators

I tried then
iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 samplecopy > out.txt

$ file out.txt
out.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators

But the content of the file, read with vim, remains:
benützt da?s

EDIT5
As suggest in the chat, I made an email similar to the one I got and posted a new question there: Mojibake (character encoding problem) when opening a converted HTML file in neovim

For those who aren't aware (as I wasn't until a moment ago), pbcopy is a MacOS command that copies data from stdin to the clipboard. https://ss64.com/mac/pbcopy.html

You face a mojibake case: Let benützt is utf-8encoded. Then benÃ¼tzt is misinterpreted in any of ['cp1252', 'cp1254', 'iso8859_9', 'latin_1'], and ben√ºtzt in any of ['mac-croatian', 'mac-romanian', 'mac_iceland', 'mac_roman', 'mac_turkish']…

many thanks @JosefZ for your comment. How could I unify all the encodings?

Why is there a non-ASCII character in "das"? There's not supposed to be one. It's just d-a-s. As to your aspirations of unifying all encodings, start with reading The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)

well it is an issue of the specific tool to set the correct encoding. In vim you could manually set it with set encoding=utf-8

Could you also add the output of file <your file with the issue>? The Vim option you're looking for is fileencodings (with an s!). That's a list of encodings Vim will try. Prepend utf-8 (or whatever encoding your file is in). You can also specify the encoding with :e ++enc=utf-8 myfile.txt. Vim's :help mbyte-encoding is also a good read.

Many thanks for your comment @Friedrich. I tried everything you said. There was some improvements (writtien in the edited question). However I am really not sure that I am using :e ++enc=utf-8 sample and :help mbyte-encoding properly as nothing special happens. Am I doing it right?

I think "das" was broken before. What was that before you converted it to text? As I said in my fist comment, the German word "das" is only three letters, all of which are in ASCII range. Encoding issues simply cannot happen there (with the encodings used today).

Many thanks for your comment @Friedrich. The original text was benÃ¼tzt daÿs which could readily be displayed converted with cat as follows: benützt das. I am aware that the "a" in "das" should be a regular ASCII, however, how can we explain those discrepancies?

Your input was broken. Either munpack (I'm not familiar with it) botched up or your HTML source already has issues.

Many thanks for your comment @Friedrich. I have similar problem with other HTML sources. Do you have another solution to propose as an alternative to munpack?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Friedrich As you suggested, I posted a new question there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78281245/mojibake-character-encoding-problem-when-opening-a-converted-html-file-in-neov
